# In Django, how do I get a signal for when a Group has a User added or removed?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In the Django admin I sometimes add or delete users to or from (existing) groups.  When this happens I'd like to be able to run a function.

I'm just using the standard User and Group models.

I have looked at doing it with signals, through m2m_changed, but it seems to need a Through class - and I don't think there is one in this case.

Comment: you can write a custom signal for this!

Comment: @fastmultiplication, I have added an answer to your question!

Answer (score 7):

From the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

> *sender* - The intermediate model class describing the ManyToManyField. This class is automatically created when a many-to-many field is defined; you can access it using the through attribute on the many-to-many field.

When subscribing to m2m_changed like so:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed)
def my_receiver(**kwargs):
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(kwargs)
```

You will receive a bunch of signals like this (shortened):

```
{'sender': <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User_groups'>,
 'action': 'post_add',
 'instance': <User: bouke>,
 'model': <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>,
 'pk_set': set([1]),
 'reverse': False,
 'signal': <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x101840210>,
 'using': 'default'}
```

So the user `bouke` has been added to `pk_set` groups: `[1]`. However I noted that the admin layout clears all groups and then adds the selected groups back in. The signals you will receive are `pre_clear`, `post_clear`, `pre_add`, `post_add`. Using a combination of these signals you could store the pre and post groups. Doing a diff over these lists, you have the deleted and added groups for the user.

Note that the signals are the other way around (`pk_set` and `instance`) when editing a group instead of a user.

Answer (score 4):

You'll see in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed) (v1.11) that your desired sender should be the intermediate `through` field belonging to the `ManyToMany` field, wherever that's defined. If you register that as your sender, then you'll be listening to eg Users adding Groups to themselves, as well as Groups adding Users to themselves.

```
self.walrus.groups.remove(self.peon_group)

@receiver(signal=m2m_changed, sender=User.groups.through)
def adjust_group_notifications(instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, using, *args, **kwargs):
    if model == Group and not reverse:
        logger.info("User %s deleted their relation to groups «%s»", instance.username, pk_set)
        if action == 'post_remove':
            # The *modification* happening is a deletion of the link
            …
        elif action == 'post_add':
           logger.info("User %s created a relation to groups «%s»", instance.username, ", ".join(pk_set))
            …
    else:
        logger.info("Group %s is modifying its relation to users «%s»", instance, pk_set)
        …
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a signal using `m2m_changed` as a receiver. According to [the official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

> A signal is sent when a `ManyToManyField` is changed on a model instance. Strictly speaking, this is not a model signal since it is sent by the `ManyToManyField`.

So, the simplest implementation is as follows:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed)
def signal_handler(**kwargs):
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(kwargs)
```

In your case, you want to perform something when a user is added or removed from a group, so you can take advantage of the `action` parameter when it takes the values `'pre_add'`, `'post_add'`, `'pre_remove'`, and `'post_remove'`. You can also take advantage of `pk_set` parameter which contains primary key values that have been added to or removed from the relation.

```
@receiver(m2m_changed)
def signal_handler_when_user_is_added_or_removed_from_group(action, instance, pk_set, model, **kwargs):
    if model == Group:
        if action == 'pre_add':
            # TODO: add logic
            pass
        elif action == 'post_add':
            # TODO: add logic
            pass
        # handle as many actions as one needs
    # The following for loop prints every group that were
    # added/removed.
    for pk in pk_set:
        group = Group.objects.get(id=pk)
        print(group)
```

Answer (score -2):

It might be better to try and achieve this with `django-celery`, that way you can write custom tasks, and based on a certain criteria (such as removal or addition) you can fire of a certain task.

- [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)
- [RabbitMQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/broker-installation.html)

Comment: I think I just need access to the auth_user_groups table in an offical way.