# How do I check if the sender is User_groups or check if the model is Group?

Tags: django, django-models

I've been googling around for hours trying to figure this out. No luck. I was looking for a way to get the signal when a group has been added to a user and this works:  [In Django, how do I get a signal for when a Group has a User added or removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899127/in-django-how-do-i-get-a-signal-for-when-a-group-has-a-user-added-or-removed)

when I follow the directions from the question above by doing this:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed)
def my_receiver(*args, **kwargs):
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(kwargs)
    print kwargs.get('sender').__class__.__name__

    if kwargs.get('action') == 'post_add' and isinstance(kwargs.get('instance'), User) :#and isinstance(kwargs.get('model'), Group):
        print "here"
        ...
```

I get the following output:

```
{'action': u'pre_add',
 'instance': <User: GzkDg2j>,
 'model': <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>,
 'pk_set': set([1]),
 'reverse': False,
 'sender': <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User_groups'>,
 'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x1010d5fd0>,
 'using': 'default'}
{'action': u'post_add',
 'instance': <User: GzkDg2j>,
 'model': <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>,
 'pk_set': set([1]),
 'reverse': False,
 'sender': <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User_groups'>,
 'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x1010d5fd0>,
 'using': 'default'}
```

This is exactly what I want but when I try isinstance(kwargs.get('model'), Group) all hell breaks loose. The model is not an instance of Group it's an instance of ModelBase. Say What?! You can see this by printing the following

```
print kwargs.get('model').__class__.__name__
```

The same thing goes with sender.

So I need to check the instance of model or sender and make sure they are either Group or User_groups.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, trying to create a receiver function for group membership changes. I ended up checking the content type of the sender to determine that the sender was User_groups like this:

`if ContentType.objects.get_for_model(sender).name == 'user-group relationship':`

The full solution looked like this:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed)
def my_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    # Check if the change is user-group related
    if ContentType.objects.get_for_model(sender).name == 'user-group relationship':

        if kwargs.get('action') == 'post_add':
            # User was added to group(s)

            # Do something ...

        elif kwargs.get('action') == 'post_remove':
            # User was removed from group(s)

            # Do something ...
```